# FlutterFlow don't start the browser download

Tags: python, download, flutterflow

I'm developing a web app with FF that launches a python script (through API). The script generates a csv file in the pythonanywhere server.
Then, in FF I run another API that runs another python script that open the file and returns the response.

```
......

b = BytesIO()
df_1.to_csv(b, index=False, sep=";", na_rep = "NULL")
b.seek(0)
file_wrapper = FileWrapper(b)
headers = { 
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment',
    #'X-Accel-Buffering' : 'no',
    'filename' : '{}'.format(filename1) 
}

response = Response(file_wrapper,
                    mimetype='application/csv',
                    direct_passthrough=True,
                    headers=headers)
return response
```

If I run the script in local, my browser starts to download the file, but in FF than doesn't happen.
I only can update a variable and print the file content in a text widget.
Is this the right method to download a file to local from another server?
I've used this method because PA not permit to download the file with a direct link to the server.
Any suggestions?

Thanks